# What is python asyncio event loop time complexity by the number of Tasks scheduled?

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, python-asyncio, event-loop

For default `event loop` in `Linux`, what is the `event loop` time complexity by the number of `Tasks` scheduled?

I want to know if a huge number of `Tasks` could be a performance issue.

Otherwise, is it just the same with `epoll` which is known that it has `O(1)` time complexity?

Comment: I don't think you will find guarantees or authoritative documentation for this kind of thing. Looking at the source of `asyncio`, one can certainly tell that it takes efforts to be responsible about using the right data structures to scale to a large number of tasks - `collections.deque` for the runnable queue, `heapq` heaps for timeouts, epoll/kqueue/IOCP for polling and so on. But software is complicated, and the only real way to know is to *measure*.

Comment: I think you are more likely to run out of memory first before you feel any significant issues with time.

Comment: @hawkcurry Have you measured? Unlike a thread, which takes up various operating system resources, including a whole stack allocated in advance, a coroutine has a tiny memory footprint - only the amount needed to hold the state of the generator and of the corresponding `Task` instance. On a modern computer you could start literally millions of coroutines before running out of memory, and it's not obvious that asyncio is actively tested with a number of tasks that exceeds a reasonable amount. If nothing else, past some point Python's cyclic GC will take long enough to introduce palpable latency.

Comment: Havent measured but while playing around with async, I've had some problems where asyncio eats up a lot of my memory. It is true that the initial memory footprint of an coroutine is small, but depending on your application, each coroutine can end up consuming a lot more than you'd expect. Let say you make a web crawler that initiates several concurrent web requests, the responses to these requests would be stored in memory.  Often times I have to set a concurrency limit to deal with this. I don't think the coroutines themselves would consume a lot of memory, but its data come with these tasks.

Comment: @hawkcurry Memory issues can arise for any reasons, many of them specific to the application. This question is concerns with `asyncio` in general, and it's an interesting question (though maybe a bit too broad for StackOverflow). Saying "you'll run out of memory first" doesn't answer it because there are applications where one can create a huge number of coroutines before you come close to running out of memory.